# how to use custom font for uilabel

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

hi i am using custom font xcode 5. its font family name is **"Alegre Sans"**  i follow many tutorials online  of using custom font in xcode.

I have include custom font file name "alegre.ttf" in xcode resources folder. also i include this file in project .plist under  **"Fonts provided by applications"**. and i am using this fond in viewdidload method of  viewcontroller like this

```
CustomLabel* lblObj = [[CustomLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(121, 30, 0, 0)];

[lblObj setText:@"FREE TRAIL"];
[lblObj sizeToFit];
[lblObj setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Alegre Sans" size:10.0]];


//  [headerLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30.0]];
[lblObj setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[lblObj setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self.headerBgVw addSubview:lblObj];
```

**but unable to change font.**

I have wasted my whole day on it but not able to change font . is i am doing mistake in programing or including font file

Comment: Possible duplication:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029660/use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-app

Comment: try rename alegre.ttf by 'Alegre-Sans' and use `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Alegre-Sans" size:10.0]]`

Comment: When you use a custom font, the name you use in `fontWithName:size:` should be the fully-specified name of the font.  This can help enumerate the fonts available to the application by their usable name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963299/cant-find-custom-font-ios

Comment: pls see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416184/using-fonts-ttf-or-odf-in-ios-applications-is-it-a-hit-or-miss-whether-they/20416481#20416481

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font's postscript name is **AlegreSans**

Update this line

```
[lblObj setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Alegre Sans" size:10.0]]:
```

to

```
[lblObj setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AlegreSans" size:10.0]];
```